# How to tell whether an Element in a list is of type <a>?

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to process only the elements of type `<a>` in a list:

```
int i = 0;
for (Element el : els) {
    i++;        
    Log.w(TAG, "--------------------------");
    Log.w(TAG, "el(" + i + "): " + el.html());
    if (el.tagName().contentEquals("a")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "<a> only! el(" + i + "): " + el.html());
      }
 }
```

But the LogCat output only shows the Log.**w**() ones, not the the Log.**d**(), although I can see clearly in the Log.**w**() output that there are elements of type `<a>`:

```
 --------------------------
 el(1): 
 --------------------------
 el(2): <a href="http://www.ddd.tld/article/ar01.html?mod=Header"><em>Subject1:</em> One line of text </a>
 --------------------------
 el(3): 
 --------------------------
 el(4): 
 --------------------------
 el(5): <a href="http://www.ddd.tld/article/ar02.html?mod=Header"><em>Subject Two:</em> Another line of text </a>
 --------------------------
 el(6): 
 --------------------------
 el(7): 
 --------------------------
 el(8): <img src="images/sub_key.gif" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.ddd.tld/article/ar03.html?mod=Header"><em>Subject Three:</em> Yet another line of text </a>
 --------------------------
 el(9): 
 --------------------------
 el(10):
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `Log.w(e1.tagName())` above your `if` - what comes out below your `<a>`s?

Comment: @Swadq Great idea. I just did that I get `b` for tag name. Weird. `<b>` is the parent element of `<a>` in that HTML snippet. Perhaps I'm confusing `html()` with `outerHtml()`?

Comment: Yes, `.html()` returns the HTML INSIDE the tag - are you need to traverse the tags INSIDE the other tags, so a nested for loop is probably the way to go in this example. If you were open to doing it another way, there should be a way to select elements by CSS selector

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax - try that to select all the <a> elements

Comment: @Swadq Yes, I'm very familiar with `select()` but my list is a generic `List<Element>`, not an `Elements` or `Document` container. Any idea how to convert a generic `List<Element>` to `Elements`?

Comment: `new Elements(yourListOfElements)`

Comment: Works! Thanks! Please post as an answer so that I can accept and vote you up. :)  (i.e. the right way to deal with this type of problem is to convert the list to an `Elements` and then simply use `select("a")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to select all elements with an `<a>` tag would be to use a CSS selector. You can use this on an `Elements` object. To convert your `List<Element>` to an `Elements` you simply use the `Elements(Element... elements)` constructor like so:

```
Elements webPage = new Elements(els);
```

From this, you can use the [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to extract the `Element`s like so:

```
Elements aTags = webPage.select("a");
```

You can then iterate through these and do as you wish with them.